# Create WCF interface from Workflow Outbound Message WSDL

Tags: wsdl, workflowoutboundmessage

Tried following [these](http://bloggiovannimodica.azurewebsites.net/post/salesforce-workflow-outbound-messages-handled-in-net-with-wcf) instruction to create a Salesforce outbound message in .NET with WCF

But I get an error when I open a command prompt and use this syntax:

```
svcutil /sc out:IService1.cs OBMTestTrexDB.wsdl
```

OBMTestTrexDB.wsdl is the wsdl I downloaded from the Workflow.

Here is a screen shot of the solution explorer:
[image]

Did I miss a step in the instructions?
Thanks,
M

> C:>svcutil /sc out:IService1.cs OBMTestTrexDB.wsdl
>   Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
>   [Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.33440]
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Attempting to download metadata from 'out:IService1.cs' using WS-Metadata Exchange. This URL does not support DISCO.
>   Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
>   [Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.33440]
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from out:IService1.cs
>   If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
>   WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>       URI: out:IService1.cs
>       Cannot obtain Metadata from out:IService1.cs.  The URI scheme is not supported by default.  Add a client endpoint in config with name="out" and contract="IMetadataExchange" and an appropriate binding to obtain Metadata from this URI.

Answer (score 0):

The following error suggests it is trying to use the `.cs` file as service description.

> Attempting to download metadata from 'out:IService1.cs' using WS-Metadata Exchange. This URL does not support DISCO.

I suspect the problem is just a missing forward slash that indicates that `IService1.cs` is the output file name.

Try:

```
svcutil /sc /out:IService1.cs OBMTestTrexDB.wsdl
```

This should work with the required format:

> /out:            - Filename for the generated code. This option will be ignored when multiple assemblies are
>                             passed as input to the tool. Default: derived from the assembly name. (Short Form: /o)

Comment: Error: The input path 'OBMTestTrexDB.wsdl' doesn't appear to refer to any existing files

Comment: Where does the wsdl need to reside?

Comment: @Michael As the command is given you will need to have the WSDL in the current folder.

Comment: Hey Daniel, the project folder?  Is this approach any different than me manually adding the WSDL as a Service Reference? Thanks, M

Comment: @Michael You should be running svcutil from the folder that contains the WSDL. Or you should adjust the path based of the folder you are running it from.

Comment: The wsdl reside in this folder C:\Users\aaaaaaa\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Salesforce OMB Test.   When I open the utility within VS2013 the syntax in the command prompt looks like this: C:\Users\aaaaaaa\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Salesforce OMB Test>svcutil /sc /out:IService1.cs OBMTestTrexDB.wsdl .  But I still get the error. I will keep trying.  Thanks for your help. M